# Sending POST request from NODE server to payment gateway

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

In my current implmentation with `MEAN` stack, for customers opting for online payment, I have created a hyperlink like this.

```
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-pram-primary btn-block" href="node/public/orders">Online Payment</a>
</div>
```

And I intercept this url in node with fallowing code.

```
var sendRequestToPayU = function( req, res, next ) {
    console.log('In sendRequestToPayU' );

    var post_data = querystring.stringify({
        'txnid': '1',
        'amount': '100',
        'productinfo' : 'ABCD',
        'firstname' : 'UserName',
        'email' : 'user@user.com',
        'phone' : '9876543210'
    });

    request({
        url: 'https://test.payu.in/_payment', //URL to hit
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'MyContentType',
            'Content-Length': post_data.length
        },
        body: post_data //Set the body as a string
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode, body);
            res.html(body).send();
        }
    });

};
```

For proper payment, control should be transferred to the payment gateway site instead, but in the process as coded above, I am not sure how I can redirect control to payment gateway ?

Should it be handled on the browser instead by creating a form and form action should be the URL of the payment gateway ?

If I follow this rule ? Should not my salt and merchant id be visible to client ?

Please suggest me appropriate way to pursue this.

Comment: What about a form with an action to your own site, and you handle the payment with your backend -> third-party gateway. However, most 3rd party payments have their own embedded platforms that can easily be included into your site.

Comment: Problem is I don't have a clue on how to send a post request from express/node server so that my client lands on payment gateway page.

Comment: So, you need a middleware to do additional things like contacting a 3rd party server. I like to use the `request` module from npm but there are other alternatives. With request, I just write `request.post('http://example.com', responseHandler).form(formData);` [This is an example](https://github.com/kdamball/NodeApp/blob/master/misc_node_scripts/zantel.js) script I use to query a 3rd party server.

Comment: My problem is to send response received from the payment gateway to the client. It should baheve like a redirect.

Comment: You can do that by using your angular `$http` service success callback. So, you send whatever info the client has through the `$http` service, and reply to it with the 3rd party response. `$http => express => 3rd party => express => $http`

Comment: Can you help with little code ?

Comment: Client would have to provide information like debit or credit card details, a client has to be involved in the payment process.

Comment: If you have CC details involved, I'd suggest you use a 3rd party app directly (embedded in your page using iframes or verified JS). In other words, I would not advise you to work with sensitive info directly, especially when you aren't sure how to handle the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem while integrating payu with my website. Although I was using php for my backend, but the solution for this problem is generic.

What you need to do is handle two forms:

FORM A : Make the user fill in this form with amount, set action of this form to FORM B.

FORM B(hidden) : This form will be hidden in your server and set the action of this form to http://test.payu.in/_payment and auto submit this form. This form will be containing all your sensitive information like merchant key and salt.

As soon as the parameters are posted in FORM B, it gets auto submit and redirects to the payu website along with the parameters with the help of action.

Your merchant key and salt is also secured in this way as the are on the server.

Comment: I had adopted the same approach for implementation. 
Forgot to update the details here.

Comment: can you tell me more? i am doing the same, but when i moved to production mode, it says the merchant key is invalid, i also have authorization header, should i be using this anywhere?